# Google Glass - how to insert a static card to the timeline using GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am using the Glass Development Kit Preview SDK Add on to API Level 19 targeting Glass XE16.2.
How can the app push a static card to the timeline on the right, without using the Mirror API?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible like it was in XE12 which was replaced by XE16 in April 2014.

From the XE16 release notes:

https://developers.google.com/glass/release-notes

```
Changes to TimelineManager:

The TimelineManager class and support for static cards from the GDK have been removed.
```

I suspect this might get resolved in a future XE update so you might want to hang tight.  If you have to resolve this now, since its possible to do a timeline insert from a server it would not be impossible to either do a timeline insert from your GDK app (but with poor security ramifications) or to send a command to a server you control with enough metadata (what user, what to put on card) so that server can do the timeline insert.  This assumes that server has previously been authorized by the user to do such an insert.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.